# How to support iPhone 3GS and iPod Touch with Region Monitoring

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, core-location, ipod-touch

I am developing an App based in geolocalization and for this goal I am using "Region Monitoring" API but I understand what that API only works in iPhone 4/4S and iPhone 5.

I want my App to work well in the most idevices possible, but i don't find information about the use of "Region Monitoring" and continue supporting old devices and iPod Touchs.

I suppose its possible to switch between Region Monitoring and GPS or WiFi localization, but I have no idea how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the 3GS does not support region monitoring, even on iOS 6. This is also true for the iPad 1 and 2 as well as older iPod Touches.

Whether you choose to include these devices is up to you. If you need region monitoring only, then you would have to manually program for this using the coarse location updates, -startMonitoringForSignificantLocation. This is less than ideal and you will have your work cut out for you. My suggestion, which is how I approach this with my own app, don't support these older devices. It stinks to have to alienate a good portion of the user base, it is not the majority base.